# Find if words are anagram, and if they are delete one of them

Tags: python

I created a function that verifies if 2 words of anagrams, and then another one that receives a sentence and deletes one of the two anagrams in a sentence. For example: 'John was going for a **race** but he has to take **care** of his son'. But without considering a word has it own anagram, for example if appears **data** two times in sentence, the two words should remain.

```py
def correct_doc(doc):
    if type(doc)!=str:
        raise ValueError()    
    elif all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in doc) and doc.count('  ') == 0:
        docl,i=sorted(doc.split(), key=len),0
        while i+1<len(docl):
            if len(docl[i])==len(docl[i+1]):
                verify_anagram(docl[i],docl[i+1])
            if verify_anagram(docl[i],docl[i+1]) is True:
                docl.pop(i+1)
                i=0
            else:
                i+=1
        doc_corrected=" ".join(docl)
    else:
        raise ValueError()        
    return doc_corrected
```

Basically, I don't know how I can delete the words if they aren't followed.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: This is actually a little easier if you don't abstract away the anagram-finding logic IMO.  Split and punctuation-strip the sentence, `sort` each word (so that anagrams will be identical to each other), and use a `Counter` to look for duplicates across the entire sentence at once, rather than comparing each possible pair.

Comment: @user2390182 In this case it would be 'John was going for a race but he has to take  of his son'. without care

Comment: @user2390182 I didn't want to consider a word as is own anagram, for example if appears data two times in sentence, the two words should remain.

Comment: What is a word is both repeated and an anagram? What should be the output for 'abc bac bac' or 'bac abc abc' or 'abc abc bac'?

Comment: @mozway it should remain only the first occurence if 2 words are anagrams, so in the first case the output would be only 'abc' and in the second one 'abc abc'

Comment: @JohnTatum quite easy, use a dictionary to keep track of the anagram and the first occurrence (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your updated question, you can use a dictionary to keep the sorted version of the anagram as key and the first occurrence as value:

```
def correct_doc(doc):
    words = {}
    out = []
    for w in doc.split():
        anagram = ''.join(sorted(w))
        if anagram in words and w != words[anagram]:
            continue
        else:
            out.append(w)
            words[anagram] = w
    return ' '.join(out)

correct_doc('John was going for a race but he has to take care of his son race')
```

output: `'John was going for a race but he has to take of his son race'`

*NB. I added an extra `race` for the demo*

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
def correct_doc(doc):
    seen = set()
    tokens = []
    for t in doc.split():
        normalized = "".join(sorted(t.lower()))
        if normalized not in seen:
            seen.add(normalized)
            tokens.append(t)
    return " ".join(tokens)

correct_doc("John was going for a race but he has to take care of his son")
# 'John was going for a race but he has to take of his son'
correct_doc("A horse on a shore carries scarier heros")
# 'A horse on carries'
```

This does not consider punctuation as the given example has none.

Comment: I didn´t want to consider a word as is own anagram. If a sentence has 2 times the word data, i want to remain those 2 words